# ExtJs 3.1.0 : the documentation (docs/index.html) does not use the same "official" ext-all.js source code

Tags: javascript, extjs

If you download extjs-3.1.0 you'll see in the folders two versions of ext-all.js:

The first one is at the root and is 649 777 bytes.
The second one is in the ext-3.1.0\docs\resources folder and is 538 956 bytes.

If you modify the `ext-3.1.0/docs/index.html` file and change this simple line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ext-all.js"></script>
```

to the "current release" :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-all.js"></script>
```

the index.html documentation doesn't work anymore.

Firebug says "sp is not defined".

If you could explain why those two ExtJs files are differents, that would help me. Actually I do think I have to rely on the root file `extjs-3.1.0/ext-all.js`, but I'd like first to make the `docs/index.html` work with it! And I can't: if I change those lines:

from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ext-all.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-all.js"></script>
```

the help file doesn't work anymore whereas **it should be able to use the "official" 3.1.0 code** (from my p.o.v.)!! What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was wrong this was a beginner's mistake... I'm ashamed to say that but...

This should've been:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-all.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-all.js"></script>
```